# Audit Envers use at mediator class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I have a doubt about the application of Envers (historical creator) in Mediator Class.

The question is, how to apply the Audit at a Mediator Class when a Object in the relation change the value.

For example, in my class ProjectMediator I have this situation :

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "ProjectMediator.findProjectMediatorByIdProject",
                    query = "SELECT pm FROM ProjectMediator pm WHERE pm.project.id = :idProject") 
                            })
@Audited
public class ProjetMediator implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String FIND_PROJECT_BY_ID_PROJECTMEDIATOR = "ProjectMediator.findProjectMediatorByIdProject";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_project")
    private Project project;


    @ManyToMany( targetEntity=Task.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
    private List<Task> tasks;

    @ManyToMany( targetEntity=Activite.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
    private List<Acitvity> activities;

    @ManyToMany( targetEntity=Phase.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
    private List<Phase> phases;
   //get and sets }
```

And I need to create a historical when the Phase object change the value, so the historical need the id of ProjectMediator, id Phase and the data Phase.

Anyone have a idea how to create something like that ?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Won't simply auditing Phase work?

Comment: @adamw Maybe yes, I think using this idea because, for exemple, if I want to know what Project this Phase pertence, I just need to get the ProjectMediator id and get the Project id. So, I save a "one" research in my data base. What you think about? (sorry about my english)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are saying correctly :)